# How to stitch drone images using jupyter lab?

Tags: jupyter-lab, anaconda3, image-stitching, panoramas, stitch

I want to stitch some images from my drone mission. I used jupyter lab. Is there anyone who knows the code/script for that?

I hope i can run the stitching process by jupyter lab.

Comment: Because JupyterLab evolved out of the Jupyter notebook project, which evolved out of the IPython notebook many people associate it with Python. However, JupyterLab is more like a development environment that can run a lot of different languages in backing kernels. Python is just one of the better known but it can do R or Juila, etc. So maybe you meant "How to stitch drone images using Python in JupyterLab?" or even "How to stitch drone images using Python?"  Do all drones produce the same file type? Then you want to cover what you've tried so far, preferably with code as text included.

Comment: Have a look on [stitching](https://github.com/lukasalexanderweber/stitching). The [tutorial](https://github.com/lukasalexanderweber/stitching_tutorial/blob/master/docs/Stitching%20Tutorial.md) is a jupyter notebook so it shouldn't be far to get this running in jupyter lab.

Comment: Thank you so much. Your replies mean something to me since I am new to python and Jupyter.

Comment: There is another problem, my drone flew at different heights, even though I had set the altitude at a certain height. So the stitching image turned out weird. Do you know how to solve it?

Comment: Open an issue If you want